# Passing same parameter to an action on clicking two different buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a View which displays a list of file names. Also i have two buttons called *View* and *Release*. When I select a file name from the list and click on view, it navigates to the appropriate action method along with the file name selected as a parameter and performs the functionality as required.

But when i click on *Release* after selecting a file name, it does navigates to the appropriate action method, but does not passes the file name as a parameter to the action method. It shows as `null`.

Please note that *View* and *Release* directs to a single controller having different action methods.

How can i get to pass the filename as a parameter when i click on release?

Please see the code below:

```
public class HoldFilesController : Controller
{
    // GET: HoldFiles
    string holdpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HoldPath"].ToString();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {       
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(holdpath);

        List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles().ToList();

        return View("Index",files);
    }
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ViewFile(string[] Name)
{
    byte[] ImageData = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
    {
        string filepath = holdpath + @"\" + Name[i];

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        fs.Close();
    }
    return File(ImageData,"application/pdf");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReleaseFile(string[] Name)
{
    for(int i=0; i<Name.Length;i++)
    {

        string sourcefilepath= holdpath + @"\" + Name[i];
        string Destinationfilepath = 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReleaseFolderPath"].ToString();
        string ReleaseFilePath = Destinationfilepath + @"\" + Name[i];
        if (Directory.Exists(Destinationfilepath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(sourcefilepath, ReleaseFilePath);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here's the code for my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "files";
}

<h2>Held files</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="border:solid;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">
        <table  align="center" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (FileInfo file in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="@file.Name" />
                            @file.Name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>
    <input type="submit" id="Held" name="Held file" value="View" />
    <input type="submit" id="Release" name="release" value="Release" />
}
```

Just to avoid confusion, the *View* button redirects to the *ViewFile* method
and the *Release* button redirects to *Releasefile* method.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 I would use the [formaction attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-HTML5 formaction and formmethod attributes**

```
 <input type="submit" name="view" value="view" formaction="ViewFile" formmethod="post" />

<input type="submit" name="Release" value="Release" formaction="ReleaseFile" formmethod="post" />
```

**2-jQuery / JavaScript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Held").click(function () {
        $("form").attr("action", "/HoldFiles/ViewFile");
    });

    $("#Release").click(function () {
        $("form").attr("action", "/HoldFiles/ReleaseFile");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options to do this.

You can hijack the submit button click and update the form action attribute value based on what button is clicked and do the form submit using javascript.

You can keep the url to the 2 action methods in html5 data attributes on the button.

```
<input type="submit"  data-myaction="@Url.Action("View")" value="View"/>
<input type="submit"  data-myaction="@Url.Action("Release")" value="Release"/>
```

Using the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct relative path to the action method is a safe practice. *Let the method worry about generating the correct path for you.*

And the javascript

```
$(function () {

    $("input[data-myaction]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // stop the normal form submit
        // read the data attribute and update the forms action and do a submit
        $(this).closest("form").attr('action', $(this).data('myaction')).submit();
    });
});
```

**Another option** is using [html5 `formaction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) which does not need any javascript hijacking. When you specify a `formaction` attribute value, it will override the parent form's action attribute. this is very useful when you have more than one submit button with 2 different action methods to submit to (your use case)

```
<input type="submit"  formaction="@Url.Action("View")" value="View"/>
<input type="submit"  formaction="@Url.Action("Release")" value="Release"/>
```