# Multiple buttons on view - different methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a view in my asp.net (Core) app, which displays a shopping cart. Typical shopping cart stuff - it lists the items in the cart. Each row has an editable field to allow changing the quantity, and an editable checkbox to allow the user to mark the row as "Delete".

I want two buttons at the bottom of the view, one for "Update Cart" (this will delete rows, and update quantities, etc). The other is for "Create Order", which will do the same as "Update Cart", but also create the order.

I have been able to create one button, and have it call the appropriate method in the controller, but I'm having trouble adding a second button, and have it call a different method.

At the moment, my view looks like this:

```
@model CustomerPortal.Models.StoreViewModels.CartViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
}

<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
<form asp-action="UpdateCart">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Price Inc. GST</th>
            <th>Line Amount Inc. GST</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CartLines.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].CartLine.ID)
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].CartLine.Item.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].CartLine.ItemSize.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].CartLine.ItemColour.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].CartLine.Quantity)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].UnitPriceInecTax)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].LineAmountIncTax)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.CartLines[i].Delete)</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" class="btn btn-default"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Order" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the methods in the ShoppingCartController look like this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("UpdateCart")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCart(CartViewModel cart)
{
    // Need to do some stuff here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
[HttpPost, ActionName("CreateOrder")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder(CartViewModel cart)
{
    // Need to do some stuff here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I've tried using "@using(Html.BeginForm" without success. The current format (as above) is the only way that it "kind of" works (both buttons call one function).

So - how can I do this? How can I make both buttons call different methods? Or maybe call the same method with a different second parameter (indicating if I create order or not).

Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to post a single form to two different controllers which is not possible by your technque try using two different forms or posting the form as ajax function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html5 `formaction` attribute to submit to two different urls from the same form.

```
<form asp-action="UpdateCart">
   <!-- your form elements -->       
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" formaction="@Url.Action("UpdateCart")"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Create Order" formaction="@Url.Action("CreateOrder")"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

When you specify the `formaction` attribute on a submit button, it will overrides the parent form's action attribute value.

Another option is hijack the button click event in javascript and set the parent forms action attribute value to the one you want and trigger a submit event, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932253/passing-same-parameter-to-an-action-on-clicking-two-different-buttons/46932985#46932985)